# Overlaying PDF on all Pages at specific location on all Pages using PDFBox 2.X

Tags: java, pdf, java-8, pdfbox

I'm trying to overlay a PDF on-top of all pages in a PDF, at the top left hand side of each page.  The PDFs that will be of different sizes. The PDF overlay is a constant size, which is smaller than all the pages of the PDF.

I can only seem to get PDFBox to put the overlay in the middle of the PDFs.

I would prefer not to convert the PDF overlay to a bitmap (PDImageXObject) and insert it onto the pages.  Here is some rough code which I'm playing about with:-

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String overlayPath = "C:\\OverlayPdf.pdf";
    String overlayOnMePath = "C:\\ToBeOverlayedOn.pdf";       
    PDDocument overlayOnMe = PDDocument.load(new File(overlayOnMePath)); //Document to write to.
    overlayPath = overlayPath + "Anno.pdf";

    HashMap<Integer, String> overlayGuide = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < overlayOnMe.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
        overlayGuide.put(i + 1, overlayPath);
    }
    Overlay overlay = new Overlay();
    overlay.setInputPDF(overlayOnMe);
    overlay.setOverlayPosition(Overlay.Position.FOREGROUND);
    overlay.overlay(overlayGuide);

    overlayOnMe.save(new File(overlayOnMePath + "_OVERLAYED.pdf"));
    overlay.close();
}
```

My gut feeling is its an affine transformation but I couldn't get that working either.

Comment: `stampPath + "Anno.pdf";` would mean that the path is `C:\\pdf2\\NuStamp.pdfAnno.pdf`.

Comment: *"I can only seem to get PDFBox to put the stamp in the middle of the PDFs."* - Yes, the internal helper method `Overlay.createOverlayStream` automatically centers the overlay. Unfortunately it is a `private` method which disallows fine tuning here. Thus, you can either use a page-size overlay with the actual stamp in the upper left (which is difficult in your case as *the PDFs that will be 'stamped' are of different sizes*) or you create a copy of the `Overlay` class and change `Overlay.createOverlayStream` accordingly.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr While it is understandable that `Overlay.createOverlayStream` is private, the calculation of the overlay position (or even the whole affine transformation, to allow for rotations etc) should be delegated to either some protected or public method (that can be overridden) or some overlay location strategy object (that can be injected).

Comment: @mkl you're right. I'll create an issue tonight.

Comment: Thanks guys much appreciate you looking into this.  Apologies for the very hacked code.  It was the result of trying lots and lots of things and giving up with a tired post on here.

Comment: If a change to PDFBox is made, it would be great for me and others if we could include the build number on here to tie up the loose ends?

Any pointers/code in creating a page-size overlay for each page to allow me to put the stamp on the top left?

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4161 created. I assume the correct y transform would be (vertical size of dest - vertical size of overlay). (y = 0 is the bottom)

Comment: The build is currently in progress, it may take an hour or two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created a new [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4161) and it allows to pass a transform, this will be in version 2.0.10 or higher. This will be done in `calculateAffineTransform` by extending the overlay class. To put the stamp on the top left, the new method would look like this:

```
protected AffineTransform calculateAffineTransform(PDPage page, PDRectangle overlayMediaBox)
{
    AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
    PDRectangle pageMediaBox = page.getMediaBox();
    at.translate(0, pageMediaBox.getHeight() - overlayMediaBox.getHeight());
    return at;
}
```

Comment: Sorry its taken me a while to get back to this.  Perfect solution.  Thanks again all, especially Tilman Hausherr.

For people who are having the same issue I created version of the stamp matching the size of each page then used the AffineTransform above to place it up on the top left hand side of each page.  Worked a treat!